# echo inside an echo - does it work?

Tags: php, wordpress

It's been a long time since I have done php so sorry for the silly question.

This is my current code, I'm trying to save the URL as a variable so that I can insert it into the echo, but it doesn't seem to work as nothing appears:

```
<?php ob_start();
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'oldurl', true);
$old_url = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments][fbcomments url="$old_url" width="375" count="off" num="3" countmsg="wonderful comments!"]'); ?>
```

I have echoed `$old_url` and can see that it has the correct value, but how do I insert the value into the `echo do_shortcode` with `url="$old_url"`?

This doesn't work either:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments][fbcomments url="echo $old_url;" width="375" count="off" num="3" countmsg="wonderful comments!"]'); ?>
```

Comment: I can see no sense whatsoever in the code shown. If `get_post_meta` returns a value that can be echoed – then why _would_ you echo it and use output buffering to capture that output, instead of simply going the direct way with `$foo = get_post_meta(…)` …?

Comment: Simply you can use `url="$old_url"` no need to write echo inside echo.. for e.g ` echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments][fbcomments url="$old_url" width="375" count="off" num="3" countmsg="wonderful comments!"]');`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to switch your quotes around. Single quotes print everything out as-is. Double-quotes will process the variables. Also, echo is not needed within an echo.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[fbcomments][fbcomments url='$old_url' width='375' count='off' num='3' countmsg='wonderful comments!']"); ?>
```

Another way to do it without switching your quotes is to break out of the statement:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments][fbcomments url="'.$old_url.'" width="375" count="off" num="3" countmsg="wonderful comments!"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not replaced in single quotes ...

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[fbcomments][fbcomments url="' . $old_url . '" width="375" count="off" num="3" countmsg="wonderful comments!"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Singles quotes doesn't allow variables parsing.

For example :

```
$var = 'Hello';
echo 'The content of my var is : $var';
// Will output : "The content of my var is : $var"
echo "The content of my var is : $var";
// Will output : "The content of my var is : Hello"
```

So you have to use double quotes or use the concatenate operator : `.`